# Erro na consulta com PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

estou criando uma página de cadastro onde tenho várias abas, conforme a estrutura abaixo:

```
<div> Aba 1 </div>
<div> Aba 2 </div>
<div> Aba 3 </div>
<div> Aba 4 </div> e assim vai...
```

Dentro de cada aba eu tenho uma consulta sql usando PDO,  só que quando eu chego na aba 4
aparece a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => 2014 [2] => Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active. Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll(). Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute. )

Eu já ativei e desativei o PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY mas nada resolve...

*** Minha Consulta ***

```
<tbody>
    <?php
        $sql5 = "CALL sp_FornecedorAnalitico_Selecionar(:codigoFornecedor, :tipo)";
        $stmt5 = $conexao_oo->conn->prepare($sql5);
        $stmt5->bindValue(":codigoFornecedor", $_GET['codForn']);
        $stmt5->bindValue(":tipo", 5);
        $stmt5->execute();
        $dadosFornecedor5 = $stmt5->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        print_r($stmt5->errorInfo());
        foreach ($dadosFornecedor5 as $pedido) {
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$pedido->codSol."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$pedido->numPedido."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$pedido->solicitante."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$pedido->empresa."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$pedido->setor."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$pedido->tipo."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$pedido->prevEntrega."</td>";
                echo "<td></td>";
                echo "<td>".$pedido->condicao."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$pedido->status_sc."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$pedido->valor_total."</td>";
                echo "<td><a target='_blank' title='Visualizar Itens da Solicitação' href='visualizar_sc.php?cod_solicitacao=".$valor->codScompra."'><img src='images/icons/search.png'></a></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
        }
    ?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Poderia colocar parte do código fonte.

Comment: coloque a parte onde faz a requisição do PDO nao só o html por favor

Comment: editei a pergunta...coloquei lá como estou fazendo a requisição do PDO

Comment: Antes desse código tem mais quatro consultas?, essa [resposta do SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2066821/1342547) sugere que você cada 'consulta' após o `execute()` assim:  `$stmt5->closeCursor();`

Comment: @rray valew... deu certo !!

Comment: O `closeCursor()` você chamou depois do `execute()` ou do `fetchAll()`?

Comment: depois do fetch(), tem diferença ????

Comment: Eu testei após o execute() e não veio o resultado da consulta, so retornou as linhas quando chamei depois do fetch/fetchAll, no meu teste não usei stored procedure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Baseado nessa [resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2066821/1342547) e no [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.closecursor.php), quando tiver que executar várias consultas em sequencia feche o curso para liberar os recurso do servidor utilizando `closeCursor()` após `fetchAll()`

```
    $stmt5->execute();
    $dadosFornecedor5 = $stmt5->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $stmt5->closeCursor();
```